# Why my state value is not updated in fetching url

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to fetch the data when the search button gets clicked, for that I made a function, on that I changed the state of data and after that i fetched the data. But the problem is in the fetching link that i had provided, it is taking the initial value of that data state not the value that i has been changed after the search button clicked.
Code:

```
         <form className="d-flex">
              <input
                onChange={(e) =>
                  this.setState({ instant_data: e.target.value })
                }
                className="form-control me-2"
                type="search"
                placeholder="Search"
                aria-label="Search"
              />
              <button
                className="btn btn-outline-success"
                type="submit"
                onClick={this.searchNews}
              >
                Search
              </button>
            </form>
```

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      instant_data: "",
      data: "",
      search_data: [],
    };
  }
```

```
searchNews = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      data: this.state.instant_data,
    });
    const link = `https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=${this.state.data}&apiKey=API_KEY`;
    const raw_data = await fetch(link);
    const data = await raw_data.json();
    console.log(data);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate);

> setState() does not immediately mutate `this.state` but creates a pending state transition. Accessing `this.state` after calling this method can potentially return the existing value. There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains.

Suggestion -> passing a callback function:

```
this.setState({
      data: this.state.instant_data,
    }, () => {
    const link = `https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=${this.state.data}&apiKey=API_KEY`;
    const raw_data = await fetch(link);
    const data = await raw_data.json();
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because this.setState is not immediate change, sometimes it takes some time to set it so you should not use `this.state.data` but use `this.state.instant_data` instead like:

```
const link = `https://newsapi.org/v2/everythingq=${this.state.instant_data}&apiKey=API_KEY`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your input to:

```
<input
  onChange={(e) => this.setState({ instant_data: e.target.value })}
  className="form-control me-2"
  type="search"
  placeholder="Search"
  aria-label="Search"
  value={this.state.instant_data} <--- added this here
/>
```

And change your `searchNews` function to:

```
searchNews = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const link = `https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=${this.state.instant_data}&apiKey=API_KEY`
    const raw_data = await fetch(link)
    const data = await raw_data.json()
    console.log(data)
}
```

**Gist**

```
// this is async operation
this.setState({
  data: this.state.instant_data,
});
```

So you end up making the call first and then update the state variable `data`

Comment: it worked but what is the point of putting the value attribute inside input field, it works without it?

Comment: Yes it does but it can lead errors down the road. @DhiranSapkota
Using `value={this.state.instant_data}` ensures that the react state is updated first and then the re-render occurs.

Comment: `Usecase:` Let's say you make an api call and update this input field using response of that. Using your initial approach you can't achieve that.
So basically, you can't update the input using some js logic. You have to necessarily type for it to show up there.
But if you pass `value` explicitly then you can achieve that